# Delete on the docker 'show desktop'

Tags: desktop

I added to docker "Show Desktop", "Power" etc.

I cant remove it from the docker now.

If I press the right mouse button, it doesn't respond(only for "show desktop", "power").

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag them away from the Plank with left mouse button.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It Works!!